# How do I extend Inverse distance weighting to take into account uncertanities?

Tags: regression, spatial

From a [Multibeam echosounder (MBES)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multibeam_echosounder) I have $n \times m$ measurements:
{$(x_i,y_i,z_i,d_i)$}$_i$ where $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ is the location of the $i^{th}$ reflection from the seafloor and di is the distance of the $i^{th}$ reflection from the MBES.

I want to grid these irregularly points to a $XY$ regular grid:

$\ x = x0 + i*dx, 0<= i < nx, y = y0 + j*dy, 0<= j < ny $

So far I am using [Inverse distance weighting (IDW)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting).

This makes sense: measured points closer to a node in the $xy$ regular grid have more say in deciding the $z$ value in this node than the measured points far away.

However the measurements are uncertain, and the larger the distance; the larger the uncertanity.

I have a simple model of the uncertanity as a standard deviation in $x$ or $y$ and in $z$:

$\ 1.96*\sigma_{xy} = \alpha + \beta*d$

$\ 1.96*\sigma_{z} = \sqrt{a^2+(b*d)^2} $

where $\ \alpha = 2, \beta = 0.02, a = 0.25, b = 0.0075 $

I want somehow to take into account the uncertanities when gridding so that the more certain measurements gets a greater say than the less certain ones.

**Any ideas on how to do this?**